# How to create a button of delete for each element rendered on screen? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm doing a simple todo app with React, just to practise. How can I delete a list item, when clicking on it?

I would want to create a button of delete for each element of my array, and each time that i clicked, the element would deleted.

I made a code but it is not working.

**My Code of Button:**

```js
handledelTodoItem(v){
  const { filtered } = this.state;
      
  return filtered
      .map((item) => {item.name}).forEach(function(i){
        if(this.state.filtered[i] == v){
         delete this.state.filtered[i]
      }
    });
  this.setState({
    filtered:this.state.filtered
  })
  console.log(this.state.filtered)
}
```

**My Code of Render:**

```js
  render() {
    let { filtered } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
        <button className='search' onClick={this.filterNames}> Search </button>
        <button onClick={this.previousPage}> Previous </button>
        <button onClick={this.nextPage}> Next </button>
        <h3>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h3>
        <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
        {filtered.map((v) => {
          return <div><h1 className="font"><button className="allbutton" onClick={this.handledelTodoItem.bind(this, v)}>DelTodoItem</button>{v}</h1></div>
          
        })}
      </div>
```

**The code all without it:**

```js
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    
    const peoples =[{id:0, name:"a"}, 
      {id:1, name:"b"}, 
      {id:2, name:"c"}, 
      {id:3, name:"d"}, 
      {id:4, name:"e"}, 
      {id:5, name:"f"}, 
      {id:6, name:"gg"}, 
      {id:7, name:"ff"}, 
      {id:8, name:"fg"},
      {id:9, name:"de"}, 
      {id:10, name:"gf"}, 
      {id:11, name:"gh"}];
    
    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      peoples,
      input: "",
      filtered: peoples,
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.filterNames = this.filterNames.bind(this);
    this.getValueInput = this.getValueInput.bind(this);
  } 
  
    getValueInput (value) {
    this.setState({ input: value.target.value });
  }
    
  filterNames (){
  const {peoples} = this.state;
   this.setState({
      filtered: peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.state.input)),
      currentPage:0})
  } 
  

  elementsOnScreen() {
    const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;
    return filtered
      .map((item) => <li>{item.name}</li>)
      .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage);
  }

 nextPage() {
         console.log(this.state.filtered)

    const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;
    
    if ((currentPage+1) * elementsPerPage < filtered.length){
      this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 });
    }
  }
  
    previousPage () {
      const { currentPage } = this.state;
      if(currentPage - 1 >= 0){
         this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1 });
      }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
        <button className='search' onClick={this.filterNames}> Search </button>
        <button onClick={this.previousPage}> Previous </button>
        <button onClick={this.nextPage}> Next </button>
        <h3>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h3>
        <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
<Pagination/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a multitude of problems with the code.

A part of the solution that you wanted will be in your **code for render** `return <div><h1 className="font"><button className="allbutton" onClick={this.handledelTodoItem.bind(this, v)}>DelTodoItem</button>{v.name}</h1></div>` the `v` between `</button>` and `</h1>` becomes `v.name`. This is because `this.state.filtered` is an array of objects and you cannot render objects. So you have to access the name of each object.

Now in your console you have a warning that *Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.* This is because in ReactJS whenever you are iterating over an array and displaying a list of items, each element in the list needs a key. This is so that React can determine which of the elements changed and which all didn't, so that when it re-renders it need to render only those elements which changed.

There are two places where you have lists. One is in the `elementsOnScreen` function and one is in the `render` function. I have added keys to the `elementsOnScreen` function and now it looks like this

```
  elementsOnScreen() {
   const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;
   return filtered
   .map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
   .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage);
  }
```

and in the `render` function, the `filtered.map` will look like this

```
{filtered.map((v) => {
          return <div key={v.id}><h1 className="font" ><button className="allbutton" onClick={this.handledelTodoItem.bind(this, v)}>DelTodoItem</button>{v.name}</h1></div>
    })}
```

Now when you click on the button, it doesn't work. Instead it has an error that says *Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.* This is because your reference of this is wrong. You have to either bind that or use an arrow function. Personally I find the use of arrow functions easier. Also you are not supposed to mutate reactjs state. Read the [docs for using state correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Your `handleTodoItem` function was buggy. I have edited it and the edits have been added as comments.

```
    handledelTodoItem=(v)=>{
      console.log(v);
      let { filtered } = this.state; // changed const to let
     // removed the return statement

   // the code here was wrong. The function below will delete the element with The
   // id that was passed to it from the array filtered.
  // then the state is changed to the new array.
    filtered.splice(filtered.map(e => e.id).indexOf(v.id),1)

    this.setState({
     filtered:filtered
    })
 }
```

Now your final code looks like this

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();


    const peoples =[{id:0, name:"a"},
      {id:1, name:"b"},
      {id:2, name:"c"},
      {id:3, name:"d"},
      {id:4, name:"e"},
      {id:5, name:"f"},
      {id:6, name:"gg"},
      {id:7, name:"ff"},
      {id:8, name:"fg"},
      {id:9, name:"de"},
      {id:10, name:"gf"},
      {id:11, name:"gh"}];

    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      peoples,
      input: "",
      filtered: peoples,
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.filterNames = this.filterNames.bind(this);
    this.getValueInput = this.getValueInput.bind(this);
  }

    getValueInput (value) {
    this.setState({ input: value.target.value });
  }

  handledelTodoItem=(v)=>{
    console.log(v);
    let { filtered } = this.state; // changed const to let
// removed the return statement

// the code here was wrong. The function below will delete the element with The
// id that was passed to it from the array filtered.
// then the state is changed to the new array.
    filtered.splice(filtered.map(e => e.id).indexOf(v.id),1)

    this.setState({
      filtered:filtered
    })
  }

  filterNames (){
  const {peoples} = this.state;
   this.setState({
      filtered: peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.state.input)),
      currentPage:0})
  }


  elementsOnScreen() {
    const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;
    return filtered
      .map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
      .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage);
  }

 nextPage() {
         console.log(this.state.filtered)

    const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, filtered} = this.state;

    if ((currentPage+1) * elementsPerPage < filtered.length){
      this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 });
    }
  }

    previousPage () {
      const { currentPage } = this.state;
      if(currentPage - 1 >= 0){
         this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1 });
      }

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
     let { filtered } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.getValueInput }></input>
        <button className='search' onClick={this.filterNames}> Search </button>
        <button onClick={this.previousPage}> Previous </button>
        <button onClick={this.nextPage}> Next </button>
        <h3>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h3>
        <ul>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()}</ul>
        {filtered.map((v) => {
          return <div key={v.id}><h1 className="font" ><button className="allbutton" onClick={this.handledelTodoItem.bind(this, v)}>DelTodoItem</button>{v.name}</h1></div>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would recommend you to do a couple of reactjs tutorials, which will help you immensely and try doing some reading on es6.

Comment: Thanks for your job, i loved.

But, i searched and didn't understand. For what it suits the `keys`. If without it, the program works??

Comment: The program does work without keys https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys